# Iterating over a Proxy in Vue Composition API

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, javascript-proxy

I have a computed value `emptyRowsRemoved` derived from the Reactivity API. I need to iterate over this value. But because `computed()` returns a proxy, I am no longer able to iterate over it with a `.forEach`.

I was curious, is the only way to iterate over the proxy is to `unRef` the value?  It seems there should be some way to iterate over a proxy. I searched for this but I cannot find an answer to this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`computed()` doesn't return a [`Proxy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy). Rather it [returns a `ref`](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/computed-watch-api.html#computed), whose `value` property contains the target data.

> I was curious, is the only way to iterate over the proxy is to unRef the value?

Indeed, you do need to unwrap the `ref` with `unref()`, or just directly reference its `.value` property to access the target array data (unless using the new *Reactivity Transform* described below).

Assuming your usage includes a `computed()` whose value is a `Proxy` somehow, such as in this contrived example:

```js
const myComputedProxy = computed(() => proxyOf(/* my array */))
```

...the `Proxy` itself should be treated exactly like the target variable. If the `Proxy` is for an array, use the `Proxy` directly as if it were the array itself. That is, you can use `.forEach()` on the `Proxy`, which will forward the call to the underlying `Array`:

```js
myComputedProxy.value.forEach(x => console.log(x))

// or
import { unref } from 'vue'
unref(myComputedProxy).forEach(x => console.log(x))
```

[demo 1](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-using-computed-ref-value?file=src/App.vue)

### Using Reactivity Transform

However, Vue 3's [Reactivity Transform](https://github.com/vuejs/rfcs/discussions/369) (experimental as of `vue@3.2.26`) avoids the requirement of unwrapping the `ref`, but you must use a [`<script setup>` block](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html) (instead of `setup()` in the Options API). Instead of importing `computed` (or `ref`) from `vue`, use the globally defined `$computed` (or `$ref`) compiler macros:

```html
<script setup>          
const myComputedProxy = $computed(() => proxyOf(/* my array */))
myComputedProxy.forEach(x => console.log(x))
</script>
```

[demo 2](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-using-computed-ref-value-doyngf?file=src/App.vue)

Comment: Thanks for this explanation and the link to the rfcs! Finally no more need for `.value`